# preg match for digits and alphabet

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm making `preg_match` that allows 7-10 digits.

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{7,10}/', $studentID
```

Also another `preg_match` code that allows maximum of 20 alphabets with space and hyphen.

```
preg_match ('/^[a-zA-Z -]{,20}+$/i', $familyname
```

Both of these are not working.

Comment: neither of your statements are properly closed w/ `);`

Comment: `a-zA-Z` with `/i` is redundant. `/i` makes the regex case insensitive already, so it's pointless to provide upper AND lower case versions. and `{,20}+` also doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add anchors to the first regex the same way you used them with the second pattern, and you must define the lower bound for the limiting quantifier in the second pattern (say, 0 to 20):

```
$studentID = "1234567";
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{7,10}$/', $studentID)) {
    echo "$studentID matched!\n";
}
$familyname = "Pupkin";
if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z -]{0,20}$/i', $familyname)) {
    echo "$familyname matched!";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/uTOmzh)

Note that `{0,20}` and its possessive `{0,20}+` version will work the same here since the pattern is not followed with other consuming subpatterns (so, no need to disable backtracking for the quantified subpattern).

Also, `'/^[A-Z -]{0,20}$/i'` is a very generic subpattern for surnames, you might want to further precise it. E.g., to disallow strings like all spaces or `---------`, you may use `'/^(?=.{0,20}$)[A-Z]+(?:[ -][A-Z]+)*$/i'`.